# How to suppress an icon on a tabbed document

Tags: mfc, tabs, icons

I have a tabbed document that is an extension class of the CMultiDocTemplate class. When displayed, an icon appears next to the text on the tab itself.

I have found the actual icon that is displayed, and when I comment out the line that references it, a default icon is displayed instead.

How can I suppress the display of this icon?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a tabbed document that is an extension class of the CMultiDocTemplate class

What is "an extension class of the CMultiDocTemplate"? Is it class **derived from** CMultiDocTemplate?

If you are using custom code, to control something how anybody can answer question about it without knowing a code.

Could you please give more detailed information, possibly code snippets and most desireable, a sample app that demonstrate you problem .

Comment: Though my class is derived from CMultiDocTemplate, I have no code that would impact the display of the icon on the tab. That is what I would like to remove/supress. For the purposes of the question, it is safe to assume I have an instance of CMultiDocTemplate